# SQL - Combine multiple text records to one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I want to combine multiple text records to one.
I have a table with data like this:

```
+----+---------+
| id | comment |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Peter   |
| 2  | is      |
| 3  | stupid  |
+----+---------+
```

I want `Peter is stupid` as output.

Do you have any idea?

I am sorry for my bad SQl knowledge.

Comment: Check out `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT comment GROUP_CONCAT(comment SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Groupo by is not needed. It will not give the result as expected

Answer (score 1):

Just to be safe, use `order by` along with `group_concat` as there is no guarantee that the data will always be returned in same order until you use an `order by`

[Rextester Sample](http://rextester.com/GESXF28415)

```
select 
  group_concat(comment order by id separator ' ') 
from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(comment SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM table_name
```